# Rendering to OpenGL framebuffer object doesn't work correctly on some ATI GPUs

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I'm using framebuffer objects to speed up rendering - everything is rendered to framebuffer object attached to a texture, the texture is rendered to the window. Everytime a part of the scene is changed, it is updated in the framebuffer object, so that it is not necessary to render everything all the time.

This works, but on some ATI cards it looks like the framebuffer size is not correct - it looks like there is some kind of 512x512 limit or something. All functions seem to work correctly, so the program doesn't see any difference, but just part of the texture is rendered.

The only difference I see is that these GPUs have a very low maximum texture size limit - 2048.

Any ideas how to fix this or at least detect that the framebuffer object doesn't work properly?

This is the code (simplified):

```
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &FrameBuffer);
        if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuffer);
            glGenTextures(1, &FrameBufferTexture);
            if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            { 
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FrameBufferTexture);
                glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuffer);

                glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, FrameBufferTexture );
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, sz.X, sz.Y, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
                glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL );

                // Attach the texture to the framebuffer.
                glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, FrameBufferTexture, 0);

                // Set the list of draw buffers.
                GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
                glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

                // Done!
                if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
```

Comment: "Just part of the texture is rendered"? Are you sure you setup your viewport correctly?

Comment: It seems so from the screenshots, but it's hard to say, I don't have any of these computers. It works in 99% systems, but in these old ATI drivers it doesn't for some reason. No error reported, nothing...

Comment: what's your platform, if it's `linux`, ensure you have latest driver and `mesa` installed...

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's Windows. It seems that ATI in general is a problem...

Comment: if it's effectively windows, ensure that you are using gl libs from the latest ati driver.

Comment: All customers say they installed the latest drivers, but no change.